# How to remove all resources created by aws federated user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I have a usecase where I had created federated user on fly and allowed access to perform actions on aws for 30 minutes. After that I will take access back from federated user but I need to delete resource created by him through an automated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on @Arafat Nalkhande's answer, cloud trail can keep track of what to delete, but it still leaves the question of how to trigger when to delete.

If your duration were shorter (15 min or less), you could put a task in SQS that could delay, then fire a lambda that looked through cloud trail and execute deletions.
One possible solution for 30 min scheduling would be to trigger a lambda a soon as the federated user logs in. This first lambda would create a 2nd lambda associated with scheduled event [as explained here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html). This second lambda would need to contain the user's info, instructions for deleting all of the resources they created, and instructions to deleted the scheduled event (so it does not keep running every 30 min).

Can you share more of the use case? If all your users are creating are s3 objects, and the amount of time did not have to be exactly 30 min, you could set up a bucket life cycle to delete after 24 hours.

Comment: Hi Sawyer, I am creating a exercise area where user can perform instructed exercise in allotted time. S3 is just a usecase it could be ec2 exercise or some other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWS Cloudtrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) for that.
Using AWS Cloudtrail you can get all the actions performed by a specific user

Following is a sample AWS CLI command to list out all actions performed by a user

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=Username,AttributeValue=Some.Federated.User@MyCompany.com
```

Once you have that you can extract the list of all resources created by the user and then delete them accordingly.

Following is a sample event that you get when user created an SNS Topic

```
{
    "EventId": "HHHHe1bc-73b1-4c0c-bcaa-6666947f3eec",
    "Username": "Some.Federated.User@MyCompany.com",
    "EventTime": 1534234453.0,
    "CloudTrailEvent": "{\"eventVersion\":\"1.05\",\"userIdentity\":{\"type\":\"AssumedRole\",\"principalId\":\"KKKKAJOTFHFJGLLFGHJF34:Some.Federated.User@MyCompany.com\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:sts::888888888888:assumed-role/dev/Some.Federated.User@MyCompany.com\",\"accountId\":\"888888888888\",\"accessKeyId\":\"ASIA53RBKAC2XUI7CT5W\",\"sessionContext\":{\"attributes\":{\"mfaAuthenticated\":\"false\",\"creationDate\":\"2018-08-14T08:11:35Z\"},\"sessionIssuer\":{\"type\":\"Role\",\"principalId\":\"KKKKAJOTFHFJGLLFGHJF34\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:iam::888888888888:role/dev\",\"accountId\":\"888888888888\",\"userName\":\"dev\"}}},\"eventTime\":\"2018-08-14T08:14:13Z\",\"eventSource\":\"sns.amazonaws.com\",\"eventName\":\"CreateTopic\",\"awsRegion\":\"us-east-1\",\"sourceIPAddress\":\"121.244.109.2\",\"userAgent\":\"aws-cli/1.11.47 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.5.10\",\"requestParameters\":{\"name\":\"Temp6789\"},\"responseElements\":{\"topicArn\":\"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:888888888888:Temp6789\"},\"requestID\":\"3787d2fe-a88c-53ee-h328-81123919c93e\",\"eventID\":\"HHHHe1bc-73b1-4c0c-bcaa-6666947f3eec\",\"eventType\":\"AwsApiCall\",\"recipientAccountId\":\"888888888888\"}",
    "EventName": "CreateTopic",
    "EventSource": "sns.amazonaws.com",
    "Resources": []
}
```

And you can use any of the available AWS SDKs to do this programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing a kind of playground area for an user and just need to discard the junk, maybe the best solution is to create an [Organization](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/) and provision the account for the user [API_CreateAccount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAccount.html) , grant only the rights they need then run a CloudWatch rule each 1 minute to check which accounts can be deleted. Much easier to track and less apis to call.

Comment: But can we create aws organization on fly and remove them on fly once expiration period is over?

Comment: Also we can destroy resources in this case.